# Read Icecast Metadata with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, icecast

I am working on a web radio application, based on AngularJS and Laravel 5, which reads Icecast streams. For now, I'm loading the stream into an html5 audio element and it works perfectly fine. Every 5s, I call a backend method which returns the currently playing song information and I'm able to update the view with the new title, artist...

But I'm facing an issue : the view is updated a few seconds (sometimes up to 40s) before the song really starts. It might be due to some browser buffering.

Now, I'm trying to read the songs' information from the icecast metadata. Is there a way to get the metadata every time it's in the stream in JS? That would be perfect, I won't have any latency issue and I won't have to call the backend every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox(gecko) does have a vendor specific JavaScript API for HTML5 metadata. I believe I explained that elsewhere on SO.

I'm not aware of any cross-browser option that would work with a plain HTML5 back end.

It would take a significant CPU load hit, you could decode a stream in javascript and read the metadata at the same point of the buffer that you use for playback. Audiocogs have some open source components for that and also Wikipedia uses a variant of that for browsers that don't support native playback.